# How to enable proxy protocol v2 in Nginx Ingress Controller on Kubernetes?

Tags: nginx, proxy, nginx-ingress, ingress-controller, proxy-protocol

I have a Kubernetes environment set up with an Nginx Ingress Controller to route traffic to my pods. I found that Nginx starting from version 1.13.11 supports proxy protocol v2 (as documented here: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/using-proxy-protocol/).

Given this, I am interested in enabling proxy protocol v2 in my Nginx Ingress Controller. However, I'm a bit confused about how to do that.

When the Ingress Controller creates a pod to handle traffic routing, it's setting up an instance of Nginx, correct? So theoretically, it should be possible to enable proxy protocol v2 in the Ingress Controller.

Could someone provide guidance on how to enable proxy protocol v2 in the Nginx Ingress Controller? And, if possible, provide an example configuration or any necessary changes to Kubernetes resources?

I'm using it on a test environment with nginx ingress controller and metallb installed.

Thank you in advance for any help or guidance!